# Getting a UnreachableBrowserException while using ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The piece of code is:

another edit: would like to note that I'm using java to implement this so I don't think slashes would be a problem. (though correct me if i'm wrong)

edit: One more thing i'd like to add is that it actually says its starting up the chrome driver version something but immediately fails after that

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

and the error i'll end up getting is

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
System info: host: '****-PC', ip: '10.10.10.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
```

There isn't a stack trace and this happens immediately after the webdriver attempts to start. I'm guessing the code above is where it happens simply because netbeans doens't really indicate where it errors out.

The mystery is that this worked on my computer but upon attempting to run it on a colleague's computer it simply produces this error. Firefox works for her but both IE and Chrome results in this. Any ideas?

edit: apparently there is a stack trace:

```
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
 at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for     [http://localhost:8891/status] to be available after 20002 ms
 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
 at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
 ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
 at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
 ... 11 more
```

Comment: What happens when chromedriver.exe is executed directly by dbl clicking it? do you get any errors then?

Comment: It just says starting up the driver in a cmd window. Nothing else after that

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add the absolute path which in Windows may need to include escaped backslashes e.g.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Or you can add the property to your System path.

If these options don't work it may be that there is a problem connecting to ChromeDriver. In which case you can open up the Chromedriver.exe file

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:9515", DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

> webdrivers/chromedriver.exe

I suspect it could not find chromedriver. Are you sure this is the right path to `chromedriver.exe`?

You should probably try with absolute path.

For example `C:/Users/Name/Desktop/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Yeah my colleague tried the absolute path and it still didn't work mysteriously. But usually if I give it the wrong path it'd give me a different exception such as ".exe is not available".

Comment: axidus1989, Did you try double slash // instead of single slash / in path of chromdriver mentioned by Amith? I think that should work.

Comment: I'm using java which translates /'s to \\ in windows so it shouldn't be whats causing the problem but I'll ask my colleague to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are working with latest Chrome browser with one version behind and
2. The latest `Chromedriver.exe` version **2.9**
3. The path should be mentioned like `C://Test//chromedriver.exe`

Comment: just realized she wasn't using the latest version. I'll leave her a note to see if this will fix it

Answer (score 0):

When I used the absolute path, it was giving me the error. However, when I used the directory where the executable was located, it started just fine.  Here is a C# example

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; 

public class ChromeOptionsWithPrefs : ChromeOptions
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> prefs { get; set; }
}

public static void Start()
{
    var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
    options.AddArguement("-incognito");
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\FilePath\", options))
    {
        //perform the test
        driver.Navigate().GoToURL(@"http://www.google.com"); 
        driver.Quit(); 
    }
}
```

I just use the prefs to not store any data on whatever machine I am running the tests on. It  is not needed, but you can pass some interesting options with it.

Comment: I'm using Java to code this up so after superficially trying this out it gave me an error that the executable was a directory thus I don't think this works.